# Cancel \everymath{\displaystyle}

Tags: displaystyle

Is it possible in a document to cancel the command `\everymath{\displaystyle}`?

It is in the `macros.sty` file I use but I would like to cancel it in some documents without changing my macros file.

Comment: Just don't do `\everymath{\displaystyle}` to begin with. It's wrong, utterly wrong.

Comment: Yes, I read it in other posts. Thanks, I'll pass the info ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declaring `\everymath{}` should do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\everymath{}

\begin{document}
This is not display style: $\frac{a}{b}$
\end{document}
```